# SQL stored procedure parameters when calling from code

Tags: c#

Does the order of parameters being passed to a stored procedure matter from the C# function?

Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's difficult to know what you're asking for. Can you edit and clarify your question? Thanks.

Comment: Please formulate your question again this makes no sense.

Comment: It's hard to tell, what you are asking here. Anyway, I made a guess and provided you with an answer. Check if it helps.

Comment: Who ever closed this one and said its not a real question, can you not understand the question, what being missed? I would say seriously, don't bother in answering the question if you don't understand just leave it there, But please behave like a professional and mature people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can add the parameters in any order, as long as the names match.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `ParametersCollection` it doesn't matter, because the parameters are specified by name.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn’t matters the order of parameters passed to SP from C# as they can be identified by their name.